# How to take table data into an array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to take value form dynamic table and send the value in ajax call, I dynamically increase table row but when I try to take row value into an array it only stores first-row value.

My HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm" id="SizeTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="allGridCheck"></th>
        <th style="width: 50%;">Size</th>
        <th style="width: 50%;">Quantity</th>
        <th class="hidden"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="GridContent table-secondary" id="GridBody">
    <tr class="GridFields">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="singleGridCheck"></td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm size-id" name="SizeId"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm quantity-value" name="QuantityValue" />
        </td>
        <td class="hidden"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And here is my script:

```
var sizesId = [];
var sizesValue = [];

$('#SizeTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
  var sizeId = $('.size-id option:selected').val();
  var sizeValue = $('.quantity-value').val();

  if (sizeId) {
    sizesId.push(sizeId);
  }

  if (sizeValue) {
    sizesValue.push(sizeValue);
  }

  alert(sizeId);
});

alert(sizesId);
alert(sizesValue);
```

How can I take the value into the array???

Answer (score 0):

because you always take the selected item

```
$('.size-id option:selected').val();
```

its normal to get one item in your array

Use this

```
$('#SizeTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {


           var sizeId = $(this).find('.size-id').val();
           var sizeValue = $(this).find('.quantity-value').val();

           if (sizeId) {
               sizesId.push(sizeId);
           }

           if (sizeValue) {
               sizesValue.push(sizeValue);
           }

           alert(sizeId);
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below modified code to get the values of your dynamic table.

```
var sizesId = [];
var sizesValue = [];
$('#SizeTable > tbody  > tr > td').each(function(ind, val) {
     var varSizeId = $(val).find(".size-id option:selected").text();
     var varSizeValue = $(val).find("input[name='QuantityValue']").val();
     if (varSizeId) {
         sizesId.push(varSizeId);
     }
     if (varSizeValue) {
         sizesValue.push(varSizeValue);
     }
 });
 console.log(sizesId);
 console.log(sizesValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery Makes Us Lazy and Not See the Obvious

I thought on the complexity and redundancy of going through every cell and then it dawned on me, your `<table>`'s values are not from the `<table>` but by the `<select>` and `<input>`. A jQuery Object is like an Array in many ways so just ignore the table and just work with the objects themselves. BTW getting the value from a select is much simpler than what you are trying in your code. Simply get the value from select:

> ```
> var value = $('select').val(); // jQuery
> var value = document.querySelector('select');  // JavaScript
> ```

Real quick explanation. You need to iterate (a.k.a. loop ➰) the correct jQuery Objects. If you are looking for the values of a group of `<select>`s, do not iterate through the `<table>`...iterate through the group of `<select>`s

---

### Demo

```js
$('#rowBtn').on('click', addRows);
$('#delData').on('click', deleteData);
$('#fillTab').on('click', fillTable);
$('#xtcData').on('click', extractData);
$('.chkAll').on('change', checkAll);



function addRows(e) {
  var dock = $('#gridCore');
  var row = $('.gridRow');
  var qty = Number($('#rowUI').val());
  var rQty = $('#gridTable')[0].rows.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
    var dupe = row.clone(true, true).appendTo(dock);
    dupe.find(':checkbox').addClass('chk');
  }
  return console.log(`
  Rows.: ${parseInt(rQty, 10)}
  Cells: ${parseInt(rQty, 10) * 2}`);
}

function fillTable(e) {
  $('.size, .qty').each(function() {
    var sVal = ["S", "M", "L"];
    var sRng = getRandom(0, 2);
    var qRng = getRandom(0, 600);
    if ($(this).is('.size')) {
      $(this).val(sVal[sRng]);
    } else {
      $(this).val(qRng);
    }
  });
}

function extractData(e) {
  var sz = [];
  var qy = [];
  var sZqY = {};
  $('.size, .qty').each(function(idx) {
    if ($(this).is('.size')) {
      var SV = $(this).val();
      sz.push(SV);
    } else {
      var QV = $(this).val();
      qy.push(QV);
    }
  });
  sZqY.qty = qy;
  sZqY.size = sz;
  return console.log(JSON.stringify(sZqY));
}

function deleteData(e) {
  var rows = $('#gridTable')[0].rows.length;
  var chx = $('.chk');
  chx.each(function(idx) {
    var row = $(this).closest('.gridRow');
    if ($(this)[0].checked) {
      row.remove();
      rows--;
      if (rows === 1) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  return console.log(rows);
}

function checkAll(e) {
  if ($(this)[0].checked) {
    $('.chk').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('.chk').prop('checked', false);
  }
  return $('.chk').prop('checked');
}

function getRandom(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block
}

#xtcData,
#fill {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: 0s
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form id='ui'>

  <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#colA">
    Table Tools
  </button>

  <header class="collapse" id="colA">
    <aside class="card card-body" style='padding:0;line-height:1;'>
      <label class="input-group mb-3" for='rowUI'>
  <input id='rowUI' type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Number of Rows" min='1' max='100' style='text-align:center;'>
  <label class="input-group-append" for='rowBtn'>
    <button id="rowBtn" class="btn btn-warning" type="button" >Generate Rows</button>
  </label>
      </label>

    </aside>
    <button id='delData' class="btn btn-danger float-right" type='button'>
    Delete Data
  </button>
    <button id='xtcData' class="btn btn-info float-right" type='button'>
    Extract Data
  </button>
    <button id='fillTab' class="btn btn-success float-right" type='button'>
    Fill Table
  </button>
  </header>

  <table id="gridTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:5%;"><input class="chkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
        <th style="min-width: 60%;">Size</th>
        <th style="width: 30%;">Quantity</th>
        <th class="hidden"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="gridCore" class="table-secondary">
      <tr class="gridRow">
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm size" name="size">
            <option value=''>Pick a Size</option>
            <option value='S'>Small</option>
            <option value='M'>Medium</option>
            <option value='L'>Large</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm qty" name="qty" min='1' max='600' style='text-align:center'>
        </td>
        <td class="hidden"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```